# Visual Studio 2015 - no c/c++ properties, but file is cpp

Tags: c++, properties, visual-studio-2015

I need to include an additional directory to my project, so I right clicked and pressed "main.cpp properties" ("main.cpp" is my project) to go to the c/c++ properties, but I don't see them.

[image]

I've searched about this problem, and everyone says that such properties don't appear when you don't have at least a cpp-file... but I'm inside a cpp-file, right? Or there's something I've misunderstood?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: You usually set include directories for the whole project, but what do you think *Include Search Path* and *Forced Include File* does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the property pages of the project itself, not the file.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Yes you can, but the OP stated that they're specifically looking for their project properties, not their file properties.